# symfony 5 get id of route

Tags: php, symfony

I have a event, with id on route:

http://test/event/19

```
    event-users:
        path: /event/{id}
        controller: App\Controller\event::event-users
```

and this page get the users registered in this event.

I try change the role of the users, with the id of user, but i have only the user id, how i get the event id? ,I need get the Id of : **http://test/event/19** ,
because when i flush on my database, i get event id null.

with this i try change role user of this event,

```
      <a href="{{ path('event', {'id':user.id}  )  }}">Change Rol <a>  <br>
```

```
    eventRole:
        path: /event/user/role/{id}/
        controller: App\Controller\EventoController::eventRole
```

```
  public function eventRole(Request $request, UserHasEvento $userhasevento, Evento $evento, User $user){
                $evento = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class)->findOneById($evento);
                $form = $this->createForm(EventoUsuarioEditarRolFormType::class, $userhasevento );                
                $form->handleRequest($request);                
                if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
                    $formulario = $form->get("tipoinvitado")->getData();
                  $userhasevento->SetTipoinvitado($formulario);
                    $userhasevento->SetEventoid($evento);
                    $userhasevento->SetUserid($user->getId());
                    dump($userhasevento);die;
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($userhasevento);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('evento_detalle', ['id' => $evento->getId()]));
                }        
                return $this->render('evento/register-evento2.html.twig',[
                    'edit' => true,
                    'form' => $form->createView()
                ]);
        
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need both ids in your route.

```
eventRole:
        path: /event/{id}/user/role/{userId}/
        controller: App\Controller\EventoController::eventRole
```

```
@Entity("user", expr="repository.find(userId)")
public function eventRole(Request $request, UserHasEvento $userhasevento, Evento $evento, User $user){
    // ...
}
```

```
<a href="{{ path('eventRole', {'userId':user.id, 'id': evento.id}  )  }}">Change Rol <a>  <br>
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression

Comment: thanks ! i get id of event on my route, but when i add the @entity, but i get this fail: Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in method App\Controller\EventoController::EventoUsuarioEditarRol() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in C:\wamp\www\oat-eventos\config/routes\../../src/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\wamp\www\oat-eventos\config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.

Comment: The error is clear, you didn't "import" the Entity Annotation class. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? Just add `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;` before your `class` declaration.